# Time taken by $in query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb with node.js, Now i wanted to ask when i use $in operator does time taken by the whole query to execute increase linearly, or does mongodb executes $in operator query parallely and take same time to execute whole query as does a single query.

Example- Suppose below query execute in N time.

```
db.student_coupons.find({ amount: { 3225 })
```

Now Does below query take 5 * N time or will take equal N time as above query ??

```
db.student_coupons.find({ amount: { $in: [3225, 623423, 6645345, 346565, 8484858] } })
```

Comment: try for yourself. calculate Time before and after sending the query. the difference b/w them, should tell you what you need. you can use language binding (java, python etc. whichever you are comfortable with) to make a query so that you can add time-related calculations.

Comment: i ran mongodb query and checked executiontimemilis but it was 0 for both of them as i don't have much data in mongodb right now, that's why i am asking this question here ??

Comment: Better dump the data as per your needs and then run your query. There is no straight answer available related to this question. You should benchmark by yourself.